# How to track AdWords Form Click Conversion's using SquareSpace, Google Tag Manager and Adwords?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, squarespace

I've researched several sources to try and understand how to set up this up, but the documents found seem incorrect our out of date. I'm trying to achieve the following.

When someone submits on my 'contact us' form, I'd like to track that as a conversion in AdWords.

I've completed the following:
- Set up the Conversion in AdWords
- Added the Google Tag Manager code to Squarespace and validated it works

I'm struggling to understand what needs to happen next, I believe it is something like:
- Create a GTM AdWords tag and add in AdWords Conversion ID and Conversion Label

- Set the trigger as a form submission

Do I then need to add some form of code into Squarespace on the contact us page to pick up the trigger? this is the part I'm stuck on.

Any guides that explain this in full would be great.